# How can I restore an xkilled panel in Linux Mint without a reboot?

Tags: command-line, linux-mint

In Terminal, one can enter 'xkill' as a command which lets you select a window whose client you wish to kill.  In fact, it can even be used to kill panels.

How can I restore an xkilled panel in Linux Mint without a reboot?

Something that I generally do in Windows is Ctrl+Alt+Delete and then restart the explorer.exe service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>Alt+F2</kbd> and then enter `cinnamon --replace` might fix it.

Comment: This works if the user has cinnamon. Mint comes in several flavours

Answer (score 1):

I waited around for a little while (~5 minutes) and it came back on its own.  Not sure if this is my only option, but, hey, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

X has a "kill this server" key combination which is often Ctrl-Alt-Backspace. Under Ubuntu this is disabled by default but can be re-enabled through Settings→Keyboard Layout→Options. This is a pretty dramatic event to all the applications that are using that XServer, so be aware that running shells, editors, etc. will get **no opportunity for graceful shutdown**.

I don't know if restarting explorer.exe is as drastic as this to running applications.

If you could be more specific as to what you mean by "xkilled taskbar" I might be able to give a better answer.

Comment: Sorry, my question was poorly worded.  Check the updated version.